# What is the difference between "to spend money on" and "to spend money with"?

Tags: prepositions

He sends much money on his new girlfriend.
he spends much money with his new girlfriend.

As far as I understand in the first senc

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking:

“On”: He buys things for her, i.e. they are for her benefit. This would include things like taking her to dinner, even though he is also paying for his own food. It is aligned, generally speaking, with courtship.

“With”: Regardless of whose the money actually is, they are buying things together for their mutual benefit. This is more aligned with building a life together, or having experiences together. There is a sense perhaps that they consider their resources to be shared. Or perhaps she is also contributing, but he is spending more money than he usually would.